# Curly braces in arrays

Tags: equations, arrays

How is it possible to make a big right curly brace and have something like this in an equation array block?

[image]

My code doesn't work, can anyone find the problem? The left curly brace at the end of the array is small, not big.

```
$\begin{array}{l}
(\frac{1}{2} \pi_b+ \frac{1}{2}\pi_a) \pi_b+\\
\frac{1}{2} \pi_b(1-\pi_a-\pi_b) 
\end{array} \right. \left\} =\pi_b/2$
```

Comment: `mathtools` has an `rcases` env for this purpose

Comment: place `\left.` *before* the array and `\right\}` after it

Answer (score 4):

The `\left.` and `\right\}` instructions have to be placed outside the `array` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[ 
\left. \begin{array}{r} 
\frac{1}{2}( \pi_b+ \pi_a) \pi_b\\[1ex]
{}+\frac{1}{2} \pi_b(1-\pi_a-\pi_b)
\end{array} \right\} 
=\pi_b/2
\]

\end{document}
```