# How to rewrite this using right curly brace?

Tags: braces

I am using this formula:

```
0\leq y\leq 1\leq x\leq 2 = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0\leq y\leq 1 \\ 1\leq x\leq 2\end{array} \right.
```

which gives me this:

[image: img]

I would like to ask how I can rewrite it using right curly brace.  Thanks.

Comment: Try `\right\}` instead of `\right.`

Comment: Nope!  Doesn't work. It goes with `\left` as a pair.

Comment: What output do you expect? A right curly brace after the "system" ... Isn't it like this? If no, please make your question more clear (in order of the expected output)

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you want :

[image]

Try like this (as per my comment)

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\[
0\leq y\leq 1\leq x\leq 2 = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0\leq y\leq 1 \\ 1\leq x\leq 2\end{array} \right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I intended to do.

Comment: Thanks!  `\left.` is indeed right.

Comment: Welcome... Happy TeXing

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution from this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278969/curly-braces-in-arrays), it should be:

```
$$\left.\begin{array}{r}0\leq y\leq 1\\1\leq x\leq 2 \end{array} \right\} \Rightarrow 0\leq y\leq 1\leq x\leq 2$$
```

which gives me just what I need:

[image: img]

Comment: Will do!  Thank you so much.  What is the error in my code btw?

Comment: `\left` needs something on its right to act on it ... \begin{array} isn't something that it can act on ...